# Does there exist a device which can construct a perfect parabola?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

For instance, a compass can create a perfect circle, and two pins can be used to create an ellipse. Devices such as Spirographs can also be used to draw all sorts of continuous parametric curves. Is it then possible to construct other (simple) devices that may continuously draw parabolas? (Or hyperbolas, for that matter) If not, why not?

Comment: https://imaginary.org/film/mathlapse-constructions-by-pin-and-string-conics (The parabola starts at 1:00, hyperbola at 1:45)

Comment: Spinners for the front of propellors are / were created on a lathe - may be worth checking out...